# ubuntu 13.04 does not work after Windows8 update

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

I am using ubuntu 13.04 on my w-530 laptop. The laptop came with a pre-installed version of windows 8. I somehow managed to install ubuntu 13.04 on it and it was working very well. But, I needed to work on windows as well, so I used the boot repair to start windows 8.
It successfully worked. Here is report - http://paste.ubuntu.com/5868906/

When I logged on to windows8, it made a update and there after on restart it did not show the grub. I used boot-repair again but it does not work. I am unable to see grub and hence log into ubuntu.
Here is the report generated from boot-repair - http://paste.ubuntu.com/5869002/

Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your GRUB file (`grubx64.efi`) is missing from the ESP; or perhaps Boot Repair isn't finding it for some reason (I've heard of this happening on occasion). You've also got a number of errors relating to your ESP; summarizing a few of them:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu': Input/output error
[  382.544276] FAT-fs (sda2): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid cluster chain (i_pos 0)
[  382.544283] FAT-fs (sda2): Filesystem has been set read-only
Error: no grub*.efi generated. Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com
```

Overall, it looks like the filesystem on `/dev/sda2` is damaged. You should repair this. In Linux, the `dosfsck` utility can do the job, as in `sudo dosfsck /dev/sda2`. If that doesn't work, you should back up all the files, use `mkdosfs` (or GParted) to create a fresh FAT32 filesystem on `/dev/sda2`, and restore the files to the filesystem. You may also need to change the `UUID=` value in `/etc/fstab` to refer to the partition by the new "UUID" value if you re-create it.

This type of problem can be caused by the Windows "fast startup" feature, which might as well be called the "don't play nice with other OSs" feature. Basically, instead of shutting down properly, Windows uses a suspend-to-disk type of feature. This leaves its filesystems in an inconsistent state, which can then cause filesystem damage if anything but Windows is booted next. You should [disable this feature](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) to make it safe to dual-boot with Linux; however, be aware that this will result in longer Windows boot times. In fact, you might want to do this before using `dosfsck` on the ESP, or run `dosfsck` again after disabling the fast startup feature, just to be on the safe side.

Once you've fixed the filesystem and disabled Windows' fast startup, you'll be left with the issue of getting booting to work normally. It appears that your GRUB file has been removed. Running Boot Repair again will probably fix this; however, I'm not a fan of Boot Repair. It takes a rather heavy-handed approach that can cause further problems down the road. If you run Boot Repair, open the Advanced Options and *uncheck* the "Backup and Rename EFI Files" option. This will rein in Boot Repair's overzealous changes. If the result doesn't boot, though, you may have one of the rare computers that actually needs this type of hackish workaround, so you may need to run it again without disabling this feature.

Another option is to try my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) You can try booting with the CD-R or USB flash drive image. Chances are that will boot successfully even as your computer is right now (damaged ESP and all). If it works and you like rEFInd, you can install the Debian package; but do this only after disabling Windows' fast boot feature and repairing the damage to the ESP's filesystem.

Comment: Looks like bug 1090829.  Repeated runs of sudo dosfsck -r /dev/sda2 should eventually fix (get rid of) the corrupted ubuntu directory.  Might be easier than a new partition.

Comment: Just to bring into your notice, Online reference for boot repair shows that when I should run boot repair, the MBR options TAB in advanced options should be active. In my case, it is not active and I cant change any of the options in this tab. My main options tab also is slightly different. Is it my computer or the version of the boot-repair has changed ?